# working with php and redis

Tags: php, redis

I am new to `redis` and `predis`. I want to create a simple `sign up` form and want to send data to user email id. I have written the script for `sign up` and `email` sending. Now I want to make a `queue` in which i want to put both of the jobs. and as the user click on submit then processor should not wait for sending email. sending email should be put in a queue. and should be processed in background. please guys can anyone give me a reference of such script in `php` using `redis`.

Comment: You can put your tasks into redis and iterate over it using cron or you can use [celery](http://celeryproject.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, push the data to a redis list and pick data from the worker which is polling the list for any data and then send it by email.

Steps:

Make a new predis client `$redis = new Predis\Client("parameter");`

A predis list `$redis->lpush(listname, "Data");`

and finally a worker(Cron) which is taking data from the same list

```
$redis->rpop(listname, variable);
```

Other work around way is to use pub/sub of redis.

Try redis [here](http://try.redis-db.com/) and documentation- [redis commands](http://redis.io/commands)

Predis [examples](https://github.com/nrk/predis). In examples folder.

Comment: hey amit. i have done the basic things but i am not getting how to start with these things. is there any tutorial from where i can start begining

Comment: is there any example from where i can learn that how the things are going on

Comment: you can start with redis here `http://try.redis-db.com/` and there are redis commands here `http://redis.io/commands` . Try working with redis-cli first, predis is just a php implementation of redis.

Comment: predis `https://github.com/nrk/predis` have a lot of examples in examples folder. Check that out too.